# How is god all good if he created evil?

Tags: nature-of-god, hell, good-and-evil, theodicy

Okay so I've heard the argument that humans are the one who let evil in the world but at one point there was only God before he stated his creation process, so there was all good. God created the laws of the universe and the way it works, he created free will in the way me and you understand it. Why would he create a universe with the capacity for evil to be in it? He can see the future so he knew the end product already when he started his creation process. He could see that hell would be created and people would be sent there to spend eternity. If you had a blank slate to create your own universe and the laws of the universe why make there even a possibility for evil to exist? At one point there was nothing, only good so all good. He created the capacity in this universe for evil and since he is omniscient he would know the outcome. How could you be all loving and create this existence with the possibility for there to be evil. You may say where there's good there has to be evil but that is because we are human and that is the way we understand things, there has to be a negative to a postlitive, but that is a law of the universe that was created by God and he knew the byproduct of that.

I always see the same response to this and it comes down to Adam and Eve. But when God created Adam and eve he could see the future and what they would become and they would release evil into the world (the evil he created).

I feel as if god either isn't all loving, all powerfull, or Christianity has lost touch of God's true word and what he is about. I do believe in God but I don't think he is Christian or has any sort of book he tried to get to us considering that basic contradiction in my eyes.

I'm not trying to insult anyone's faith but I have my priest, my religious friends, and my family and they all seem stumped on the question and just chalk it up to "there's things that we aren't supposed to understand" and I feel like that's just such an easy cop out when people are so sure in their beliefs

Comment: Welcome to the group Jarginb. You asked the 64-dollar question, but it has indeed been asked before here. Please do take the [Tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour)  and familiarize yourself with the way the group works to avoid having your questions closed as duplicates or off topic, opinion-based etc.

Comment: **Important Question** It should be noted that for all intents and purposes, Evil is not "created," but Evil is "committed." This should clear up much conclusions.  It is when man commits acts of disobedience to God's principles (ethics and morality) that Evil exists.  God is good and in Him is no Evil.  (This, of course, is dealing with moral evil, and not physical 'evil' such as tornados, earthquakes, etc.. But even those are the result of the Fall of Man. For the earth groans, also waiting for redemption. See Paul.) Keep studying the Bible, Jarginb, it's great for the soul!

Comment: .....That God knew all of this ahead of time, does not impu8gn the nature of God. To explain it in terms we can understand, just think of the idea of Married people choosing to have children.  Do they know, ahead of time, that the children will be irascible, disobedient, burdensome...in need of grace, patience, forgiveness...? Yes, but that doesn't stop them from having several children. Are the parent evil, then? Hardly.